# No overload for 'OnClientReady' matches delegate 'AsyncEventHandler<DiscordClient, ReadyEventArgs>'

Tags: c#, discord

I try to make a discord bot in c# with plugin d# and I have this error that shouldn't exist
I watch a tutorial and I copy the code so it should work

```
using DSharpPlus;
using DSharpPlus.EventArgs;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DisordBot
{
public class Bot
{
    public DiscordClient Client { get; private set; }

    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        var config = new DiscordConfiguration
        {

        };

        Client = new DiscordClient(config);

        Client.Ready += OnClientReady;
    }

    private Task OnClientReady(ReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Copy-pasting is not the way to do programming. You need to understand it.

Comment: I'm new in crateing discord bots and this is just the setup and I understand basic

Answer (score 1):

Try to setup configure, bot cant start without token, make sure that he exists.

Delete "return null" from you code, this event can be empty, like all events.

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
private Task OnClientReady(ReadyEventArgs e)
```

to this:

```
private Task OnClientReady(object sender, ReadyEventArgs e)
```